# PostgreSQL insert current sequence value to another field with condition

Tags: postgresql

the issue:
i need to do something like this

```
drop table if exists tt_t;
create temp table tt_t(id serial primary key, main_id int, external_id int);

insert into tt_t(main_id, external_id)
select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tt_t', 'id')), 1
where not exists (select from tt_t where external_id = 1);
```

but execution raises an error

> SQL Error [55000]: ERROR: currval of sequence "tt_t_id_seq" is not yet defined in this session

solution:
there is a way to solve this with anonymous code block

```
do
$$
begin
    if not exists(select from tt_t where external_id = 1)
    then
        insert into tt_t(external_id, main_id)
        values(1, currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tt_t', 'id')));
    end if;
end;
$$
;
```

but anonymous blocks has some restrictions e.g. [Dapper parameters not working with PostgreSQL through npgsql connection, is postgres anonymous function parameterization supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439352/dapper-parameters-not-working-with-postgresql-through-npgsql-connection-is-post)

how do i fix it without anonymous code block (UPD: and without any DDL changes)?

Answer (score 1):

probable solution:

```
insert into tt_t(id, main_id, external_id)
select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tt_t', 'id')), currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tt_t', 'id')), 1
where not exists (select from tt_t where external_id = 1);
```

shorter code has been proposed to me

```
insert into tt_t(id, main_id, external_id)
select nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('tt_t', 'id')), lastval(), 1
where not exists (select from tt_t where external_id = 1);
```

but i'm not sure if nextval will be calculated first

Answer (score 1):

What about using a default value:

```
drop table if exists tt_t;
create temp table tt_t(id serial primary key, main_id int default lastval(), external_id int);

insert into tt_t(external_id)
select 1
where not exists (select * from tt_t where external_id = 1);
```

In theory it shouldn't be possible that another `nextval()` is called between the one for the `id` and the `lastval()`. However I am not 100% sure if there are some corner cases that I don't know of.

The following works as well (even if one or more of the external_id values already exist).

```
insert into tt_t(external_id)
select *
from (values (1),(2),(3)) x (external_id)
where not exists (select * 
                  from tt_t 
                  where external_id = x.external_id);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can not make any DDL changes.